# How to abort only function on error, but do not the script?

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function do_it {
    rm this-file-does-not-exit
    echo "Continuing ..."
    echo "Done ..."
    return 0
}

if do_it ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "End of script"
```

Which produces:

```
rm: cannot remove 'this-file-does-not-exit': No such file or directory
Continuing ...
Done ...
Success
End of script
```

The function is not aborted because running the function in the `if` statement disables `set -e` for the function (and can not be enabled). This is not what I want.

Running the function outside the `if` statement, and collecting the result, is not possible, because in this situation the complete script is aborted if the function fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function do_it {
    rm this-file-does-not-exit
    echo "Continuing ..."
    echo "Done ..."
    return 0
}

do_it
if $? ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "End of script"
```

Produces:

```
rm: cannot remove 'this-file-does-not-exit': No such file or directory
```

I would like the following:

- the script aborts whenever a top-level command has a failure
- functions are aborted whenever a command has a failure. The return code of the failing command is returned as function return code
- failure in a function does not abort the script (only the function)

This can be implemented as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function do_it {
    rm this-file-does-not-exit || return $?
    echo "Continuing ..." || return $?
    echo "Done ..." || return $?
    return 0
}

if do_it ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "End of script"
```

Which produces what I want:

```
rm: cannot remove 'this-file-does-not-exit': No such file or directory
Error
End of script
```

But this makes the implementation of the function completely unreadable: each line must be followed with a `|| return $?`

Is there another way of aborting a function, **and only the function**, whenever an statement in the function fails?

Comment: Instead of `|| return $?`, you can use `&&` and drop `return 0`

Comment: @oguzismail Makes the function equally unreadable, and following this idea for complex functions, with loops, blocks, if expressions, its own `||` and `&&` expressions,  and what not is not obvious

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. But I can't see any other way (and it's annoying)

Comment: @oguzismail interestingly, even running the function in a subshell disables `set -e`

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Wait a couple of hours btw, maybe someone comes up with a workaround

Comment: Incidentally just `return` should suffice; the `$?` argument is implied (or propagated from the previous command if you like, as `return` is a built-in).

Answer (score 2):

You can use "pipefail" to get the return code of the last executed command in the pipe.
I wouldn't say it looks much better than your code, but at least it's shorter.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ep

function do_it {
    rm this-file-does-not-exit &&
    echo "Continuing ..." &&
    echo "Done ..."
    return $?
}

if do_it ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "End of script"
```

In this case function will stop executing right after first failed command (rm) and the result will be the return code of the last command in the pipeline. If "rm <filename>" will be successful, both echoes should work, and the return code will be 0.

Output:

```
$ touch this-file-does-not-exit
$ ./script-return.sh 
Continuing ...
Done ...
Success
End of script
$ ./script-return.sh 
rm: cannot remove 'this-file-does-not-exit': No such file or directory
Error
End of script
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good with bash scripting and it would take me a lot of effort to implement my following thought, but I think this should work:

- implement a function

  - which gets an array as input
  - interrupts the commands (which were passed as strings) on failure like your example
  - returns something which identifies where it was interrupted and why (if it was interrupted)
- when you desire the behavior you described
- build an array of the commands that you would like to execute
- pass this array to the function
- handle the response

Answer (score 1):

Nice question :D What you can do is create a function that parses functions and appends `| return $?` if a command **fails**.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function _exec {
        local func=$1
        [[ ! -z $func ]] || exit 1
        local data="$(typeset -f $1 | sed '1,2d;$d');"
        while read -d ';' cmd; do
                eval "$cmd" || return $?
        done <<<"$data"
        return 0

}

function _test { 
        local ret=$1
        echo -n "[ RESULT ]: "
        if [[ $ret -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo "failure"
        else
                echo "success"
        fi
}

function _fail {
        rm thisfilewillnevereverexistonmyfilesystemsoidonthavetomakesureitdoesnt.txt
        echo "hello"
        echo 2 3 \
                multiline also works
}

function _pass {
        true
        echo "Hello world"
}

_exec _fail
_test $?
_exec _pass
_test $?
exit 0
```

How it basically works is you let `_exec` execute the functions that may not fail. It retrieves the content of the function given as it's parameter and executes it with `eval`. Note that if you would execute `false` in `_true`, the `_exec` function will fail also.

Hope this works out for you.